# Downloading tar file but getting HTML code from requests.get() function in requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a link to a Jenkins page, which when entered in the browser, prompts for a username and password. Upon entering the credentials and clicking "sign in", it automatically starts downloading the tar.gz file. I'm trying to use python on an ubuntu machine to do this task and here what I've come up with.

```
import requests
url = 'sample_url'
user = 'xyz'
password = 'abcd'
target_path = 'file.tar.gz'

response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password), stream=True)
if response.status_code == 200:
   with open(target_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.raw.read())
```

After the execution, I get a file file.tar.gz with a space of 4 Bytes but the size of original tar.gz file is around 400 MBs. Upon taking the output of the content in a text format I found out that the content of the file is the entire HTML code of the page instead of the binary file, and it looks something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US">
..............................
Keep me signed in</div></label></div></form><div class="footer"></div></div></div></body></html>
```

I tried using the function `copyfileobj` from `shutil` library, but it gives the same thing.
How do I get the tar file downloaded in this case?

Comment: What's in `response.content`? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/downloading-files-from-web-using-python

Comment: @RandomDavis The same HTML code of the page as the second code snippet.

Comment: Have you got the URL right?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Yes, When I try to hit the URL via a web browser, it works fine. When I check the ```status_reponse``` it gives 200 as well.

Comment: Why does the response include ```Keep me signed in``` then? Isn't that a checkbox usually?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur That's what I'm not able to figure out as the response has the entire dump of the HTML code of the page. When URL is hit via browser, a Jenkins page opens up and asks for username and password, upon entering the correct credentials, it starts downloading the file automatically.

Comment: The URL points towards the login page, that's why you're getting only HTML data. The data to be downloaded is on some different URL

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Thanks for the insight. The  HTML dump in the ```response.content``` had a link that it was redirecting to. I retrieved that from the HTML code and used that directly with authentication for download and it worked. Thanks a lot.